# Why it does not order

Tags: php, mysql, sql, request

i have a problem with ordering..
If I set request to s=10 or s11 ir does nothing...
i tryed to print $order on request, it worked, but it does not appear in $sql= ($order)

```
 if(isset($_GET['s']) AND $_GET['s']==10)
                    {
                        $order=' ORDER BY a.saskanojuma_nr ASC';
                    }
 elseif(isset($_GET['s']) AND $_GET['s']==11)
                    {
                        $order=' ORDER BY a.saskanojuma_nr DESC';
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        $order=' ORDER by a.id desc';
                    }



                    $sql='SELECT a.projekta_id, a.saskanojuma_nr,  a.datums, a.akcepta_nr, a.objekta_autors FROM '.$table_prefix.'_saskanojumi a LEFT JOIN '.$table_prefix.'_projekti b ON b.id=a.projekta_id LEFT JOIN '.$table_prefix.'_objekti c ON c.id=b.objekta_id LEFT JOIN '.$table_prefix.'_kadastri d ON d.objekta_id=c.id LEFT JOIN '.$table_prefix.'_ipasnieki e ON e.objekta_id=c.id  '.$query.' AND  a.buvvaldes_id='.$_SESSION['buvvaldes_id'].' AND a.dzests=0 GROUP BY a.id '.$order.' ';
        $thiss=$GLOBALS['db']->query($sql);
```

Comment: try to print $sql to see if it's there

Comment: what is the $query have?

Comment: Perhaps you're not showing enough code. What you have there should at least append ` ORDER by a.id desc` to `$sql`.

Comment: try to use $_GET['s']=="10" in if condition

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your code shown here seems correct. Perhaps problem is somewhere else.

Step by step  **banchmark** your code  and try to find where is fault.

Answer (score 0):

Try to use PHP `switch/case` syntax:

```
switch ($_GET['s']) {
  case 10:
  $order=' ORDER BY a.saskanojuma_nr ASC';
  break;

  case 11:
  $order=' ORDER BY a.saskanojuma_nr DESC';
  break;

  default:
  $order=' ORDER by a.id desc';
  break;
}
```

In case `$_GET['s']` is not 10 or 11, the value of `$order` variable will be get from '`default`' statement, i.e. `ORDER by a.id desc`

Comment: what is wrong with his code? what's wrong if OP Using if/else here?

Comment: You see, the logic is wrong, because the last 'else' statement is executed only if $_GET['s'] is not 10, but there is nothing wrong to use if/else statements in general...